# Microsoft Access Filter Query Via Combo Box

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a form in Microsoft Access that will filter a query that I have created. I have a list of computer serial numbers and the corresponding computer lab where they are located. I would like to have a form where my users can use a combo box to select a lab and then see a list of all of the computers that are in that lab. I am unsure as to how to set up this form.

Comment: Migrated from Super User .. but SO is a code helping forum, not an application writing service. You may be better helped at Experts Exchange or UtterAccess.

Answer (score 0):

Put a drop down on the form and as the RowSource enter there something lime this:

```sql
    SELECT computerLab FROM MyTable GROUP BY computerLab
```

The On Change event would look like this:

```vb
Private Sub cmbComputerLab_Change()
    If IsEmpty(cmbComputerLab) Then
        Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTable "
    Else
        Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE computerLab = '" & cmbComputerLab & "'"
    End If   
End Sub
```